# A lot of query ends occur when I execute the Alter command

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I changed the big table and I got a lot of query ends

Connection lost due to many query ends.

How can I avoid it?

"INSERT, UPDATE" have to wait until "ALTER TABLE" is over?

[image]

Comment: If the `ALTER` statement is locking the entire table, then yes, those inserts and updates won't be allowed to run, but would instead block or error out.  Just wait fro the `ALTER` to finish first.

Comment: Unfortunately, I believe ALTER TABLE always locks the entire table.

Comment: You may wish to read this: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-online-ddl-operations.html  You didn't tell us what your `ALTER` command does, so it's hard to help you further. At any rate, you'll be wise to let your `ALTER` finish before using the table.